# netCDF4 not working on transitioning to python 3.5

Tags: python, netcdf

I recently tried to transition from python2.7.11 to python 3.5.1, however having issues with netCDF4 library:

This worked in 2.7.11:

```
hndl = netCDF4.Dataset(path_file, perm, format='NETCDF4')
```

but fails with this error in python 3.5.1:

```
*** OSError: Unknown error
```

I am using the latest netCDF4 library and windows 10

Comment: This issue is known. Look at https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/issues/535. Unfortunately it still exists, despite the mentioned fix there.